# Casting Range.Value2 of Excel interop to string

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

I import some values from Excel sheets in C# application. One column is a text basically but can contain any values. I used the following:

```
Range range = ... // getting this from Excel, works fine
string myString = (string)range.Value2;
```

When the cell contains text, this is working. But when it contains, for example, 123, the debugger shows 123.0 for range.Value2 and conversion to string fails with exception.

I wonder, how to write the most general conversion for all kinds of cells. At least string and integer, may be float content.

Comment: What is the type and value of `Value2` exactly? What is the exception message?

Comment: @SonerGönül  Exception: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException Can't convert double to string. Value2 is dynamic :)

Comment: So, range.Value2.ToString();

Comment: @RezaArabQaeni yes, I just found similar answer myself, see below, Excel often returns null values also

Comment: FYI - That will blow up when range is more than 1 cell as .Value2 will return an object[] array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution which may be not so nice but works:

```
myString = range.Value2 == null ? "" : range.Value2.ToString();
```

May be something better exists.