# Reading values from Excel with C# converting double to string

Tags: c#

I have the code below to iterate through an Excel file to convert it to a pipe delimited file.

```
for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
            {
                for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
                {
                    str = str +"|"+ (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;

                }
                sw.WriteLine(str);
                str = "";

            }
```

Problem is that when I get to a numerical value I get a runtime error "Can't convert double to string"

Any ideas how I can write a double value from Excel to file using StreamWriter?

Comment: Try using `.ToString()` instead of casting it.

Comment: `str = str +"|"+ (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString()`

Comment: use Value2.ToString()

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231413/casting-range-value2-of-excel-interop-to-string?noredirect=1&lq=1 . because Value2 might be null according to that link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static string ToStr(object readField)
{
    if ((readField != null))
    {
        if (readField.GetType() != typeof(System.DBNull))
        {
            return Convert.ToString(readField);
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

str = str +"|"+ **ToStr((range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2);**

Use this way

Answer (score 2):

Casting a value to `string` like you are doing in your example, does not convert the value to a String value. Since your value is a `double` as you say you have to use the `ToString()` method to get a String representation of that value.

```
for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
{
  for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
  {
    str = str +"|"+ (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
  }
  sw.WriteLine(str);
  str = "";
}
```

[Casting vs Converting an object toString, when object really is a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170756/casting-vs-converting-an-object-tostring-when-object-really-is-a-string)